# nodejs How to get out from async.eachLimit?

Tags: node.js

here is my code -

```
function lastCB(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      if(errFlag) {
        res.send({"Message": "Some error occured"});
      } else {
        res.send({"Message" : "Success"})
      }
    };

updateabcd: function(req, res, next) {
    var Data = req.data;
    var errFlag = 0;

    function update(row,callback) {
      something.updateit(row,function(err,result){
        if(err) {
          errFlag = 1;
          //error from DB
        }
        callback();
      });
    };

    async.eachLimit(Data, 1, update, lastCB);
```

What i want to achieve is to call the lastCB of eachLimit if err comes comes inside update function even if ecahLimit is in between of array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your update function should look like:

```
function update(row,callback) {
  something.updateit(row,function(err,result){
    if(err) {
      errFlag = 1;
      //error from DB
      callback(err);
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  });
};
```

If there was an error you must still call the callback function but in that case you should pass an error object to it. When async detects that an error object was passed to it then it will stop iterating and calls your lastCB function right away.

In the above example I just passed the err object returned by the something.updateit function. But in some cases you may need to create a new error object and pass that to the callback. Here is an example:

```
function update(row,callback) {
  something.updateit(row,function(err,result){
    if(err) {
      errFlag = 1;
      //error from DB
      callback(err);
    } else {
      if (result.badData) {
        callback(new Error('Invalid data received from the database'));
      } else {
        callback();
      }
    }
  });
};
```